# "Driver is not defined" Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use Selenium on Python but I have an alert message:

> driver-webdriver.Chrome("D:\Selenium\Chrome\chromedriver.exe") NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

I have installed the Chrome Driver, what else must I do ?

Comment: Share the import statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While working with `Selenium` 3.4.3, `chromedriver` v2.30 and `Google Chrome` v59.0 through `Python 3.6.1` you neither need to install `chromedriver` nor need to copy in to any `path`. You can save the `chromedriver` in any location on your machine. To initiate the WebDriver instance you can explicitly call the `chromedriver` by passing the absolute path of the `chromedriver` through the argument  **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 1):

chromedriver.exe must be in python path, probably now python expects that driver exists in "D:\Selenium\Chrome\chromedriver.exe" but it does not. You could try add chromedriver.exe path to windows enviroment path variable, or add path to os.path in python, or add driver to folder of python script.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_your_chromedriver.exe)
```

If chromedriver is in your PATH you dont have to specify. Remember to use double slashes - or put an r in front of the chromedriver path

```
... = webdriver.Chrome(r'path_without_doubble_slashes)
```